# What does "label" mean in the SoundCloud tracks API?

Tags: soundcloud

What does "label" mean in the SoundCloud tracks API? I'm referring to the following fields from http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks:

- label
- label_id
- label_name

Does this mean the record label (e.g. Sony, Warner, UMG, etc.) that released the song, or is it something else? The documentation isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the record label.  On the SoundCloud site this will be populated under the "Released by:" item.  If there is an official SoundCloud account for the label, the `label_id` will be the user id of that label account.

Answer (score 0):

It has been updated and yes, all uploaded sounds now have a section for metadata. You can find it under the "show more options" information field when you edit a track.

The code should read:

- edit#info-fields

Additional features include adding release dates, release/catalogue numbers, ISRC codes, bpm/tempo, and key.

You can now also attach video links (Youtube, Vimeo, Dailymotion, and Viddler).

Below is a screen shot of the new feature (was denied access to post images).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG05G.jpg

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with my question.